# Error: Exception in HostObject::set: unable to put on NativeModules: operation unsupported

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, agora.io

After upgrading to react-native version 59 this issue starts coming:

```
Error: Exception in HostObject::set: unable to put on NativeModules: operation unsupported
```

It seems like it's an issues related to bable config, if someone came across this kind of issue then please help me out

Comment: Please show me the corresponding error code.